# Design OpenCourseWare course recommendation

Tags: education

I have alway been creative and interested in Graphic Design but never had any formal training. Ideally I would like to return to University to do a degree in Graphic Design, but due to time and financial contraints this isn't possible.

Can you suggest some good OpenCourseWare courses for Graphic Design (Print or Web)? The best I have found so far have been some tutorial articles, but I would prefer something that has better coverage of the theory.

Comment: You're not going to find any OCW stuff for graphic design, because MIT doesn't have any graphic design courses, and OCW is MIT's thing.

Answer (score 4):

[Teach Yourself Graphic Design](http://psd.tutsplus.com/articles/inspiration/teach-yourself-graphic-design-a-self-study-course-outline/) is a series of articles that comes highly recommended.

Comment: Not OpenCourseWare. Just tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Peer 2 Peer University has a couple of classes that are open for registration right now. One is Intro to Design and Usability which is focused on web design. http://p2pu.org/webcraft/intro-design-and-usability

There will probably be more design courses in upcoming semesters too.